# How to set up multiple frames

Tags: python, tkinter, frames

This is a simple math game which is currently in progress. The loop starts off in `mainGame()` which then proceeds to `mainMenu()`. I am trying to create 2 frames; `mframe` and `gframe` in order to `.destroy()` the frames later on, essentially clearing the previous interface for the next one (similar to changing pages).

error:

> Label(gframe, textvariable=self.question_var).pack() #gframe stands
>   for game frame NameError: name 'gframe' is not defined

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

root = Tk()
mframe = Frame(root).pack()
gframe = Frame(root).pack()
frame.pack()
start = True

class mainMenu:
    def __init__(self):
        gframe.destroy() #gets rid of previous interface
        title = Label(mframe, text = "main menu").pack() #mfame stands for menu frame

class mainGame:
    def __init__(self):
        if start == False:
            mframe.destroy() #gets rid of previous interface

        #question
        self.question_var = StringVar()
        Label(gframe, textvariable=self.question_var).pack() #gframe stands for game frame

        #answer
        self.user_answer_var = StringVar()
        entry = Entry(gframe, textvariable=self.user_answer_var)
        entry.pack()
        submit = Button(gframe, text = "submit", command = self.check_answer).pack()

        #response output
        self.response_var = StringVar()
        self.count = 0
        self.score = 0
        Label(gframe, textvariable=self.response_var).pack()

        #starts loop
        self.ask_question()
        root.mainloop()

    def ask_question(self):
        if self.count == 1: 
            self.endGame()
        num1 = randint(1, 10)
        num2 = randint(1, 10)
        self.question_var.set("What is "+str(num1)+" + " +str(num2)+"?")
        self.true_answer = num1 + num2
        #print(self.true_answer) #testing purposes

    def check_answer(self):
        self.count += 1
        user_answer = self.user_answer_var.get()
        #print(user_answer) #testing purposes
        if int(user_answer) == self.true_answer:
            text = "Good job"
            self.score += 1
        else:
            text = "Oh no"
        self.response_var.set(text)

        #clear answer for next loop
        self.user_answer_var.set("")
        self.ask_question()

    def endGame(self):
        print("endGame")
        mainMenu()


mainGame()
```

Comment: I don't see where are you creating said two frames. There is only one Frame creation in this code and that it `frame`. You actually should create your frames like `mframe = Frame(root..)` etc.

Comment: Sorry but I have never used frames before, do you mean:
mframe = Frame(root)
gframe = Frame(root)
Becuase a new error occurs:
frame.pack()
NameError: name 'frame' is not defined

Comment: You need to `pack` what you have defined. Right now, there is no `frame`, there are `mframe` and `gframe`.

Comment: Ah, so  I've done `mframe = Frame(root).pack()
gframe = Frame(root).pack()` and removed the frame in  `frame.pack()` But now: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'` seems to be a problem when it wasn't before in the original code

Comment: Now your mframe/gframe are `None`s because `pack()` returns `None`.

Comment: Does that mean that I have to change `.destroy`  or something to do with the `.pack()`

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but that means you should follow a tutorial and/or search for "NoneType tkinter".

Comment: No offence taken! Thanks for everything up to this point.

Comment: I apologise but I'm still stuck, nothing I've come across seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments above, the `pack()` method returns `None`. What you need to do is first create the two frames and assign them to variables, then pack them later. This way, the variables still point to the frame instances and not `None`.

You should change;

```
root = Tk()
mframe = Frame(root).pack()
gframe = Frame(root).pack()
frame.pack()
start = True
```

to;

```
root = Tk()
mframe = Frame(root)
gframe = Frame(root)
mframe.pack()
gframe.pack()
start = True
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works fine now thanks again :)

Comment: You're very welcome. Consider accepting/upvoting the answer if it works for you.